# Error: Hydration failed because the initial UI does not match what was rendered on the server next js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

Error: Hydration failed because the initial UI does not match what was rendered on the server.

Warning: Expected server HTML to contain a matching  in .

```
"use client"
import { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import Head from "next/head";

const UnderDevelopment = () => {
  return (
    <>      
<Head>
        <title>Under Development - My Site</title>
      </Head>
      <h1 className="text-3xl font-bold mb-4">This page is under development</h1>
    </>
  );
};

export default UnderDevelopment;
```